# Android WebView inside ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-webview

I have a `WebView` inside a `ListView`. Everything works fine, except that I can't block the `ListView` from scrolling up/down, if the `WebView` handles the scroll gesture.

I know, that I can completely block scrolling of the `ListView` with following code in the OnTouchListener

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        webView.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
    } else {
        webView.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    }
}
```

but I only want to block it, while the `WebView`didn't handle the scroll/touch gesture.

Eg. I have two HTML-pages. One shows a 360 View of a location. This `WebView` should block scrolling of the parent completely, while the second `WebView` is just text. The page would not handle the touch events and therefore, the parent `ListView` can scroll.

PS: The HTML is not written by myself and can't be modified.

Answer (score 2):

Followed by @mars3142, below code shows and allows to scroll more like a webpage shown in the browser.

```
public class InnerScrollWebView extends WebView {

    private Boolean enableScroll = true;

    public InnerScrollWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            enableScroll = true;
        }
        if (getParent() != null) {
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(enableScroll);
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onOverScrolled(int scrollX, int scrollY, boolean clampedX, boolean clampedY) {
        if (getParent() != null) {
            enableScroll = false;
        }
        super.onOverScrolled(scrollX, scrollY, clampedX, clampedY);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should place this on the parent layout of each webview and it should do the trick.

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by creating a custom `WebView` and it seems to work really good.

```
public class CustomWebView extends WebView {

    private Boolean enableScroll = true;

    public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr){
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            enableScroll = true;
        }
        if (getParent() != null) {
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(enableScroll);
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onOverScrolled(int scrollX, int scrollY, boolean clampedX, boolean clampedY) {
        if (getParent() != null) {
            enableScroll = false;
        }
        super.onOverScrolled(scrollX, scrollY, clampedX, clampedY);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have just override the on touch event

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.android.gms.internal.ev;
import com.google.android.gms.internal.ol;
import com.notifyme.R;
import com.notifyme.test.InteractiveScrollView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    ListView listView;
    Map<Integer, List<Float>>  map = new HashMap<Integer, List<Float>>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.test_activity);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_test);

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.test_activity);
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
        strings.add("http://youtube.com");
        strings.add("https://google.com");
        strings.add("http://www.tutorialspoint.com/");
        strings.add("http://stackoverflow.com/");
        adapter.addAll(strings);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            /*
             * RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
             * RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new
             * RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
             * RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
             * RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); params1.height = 600;
             * ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(getContext());
             */
            /*
             * scrollView.setLayoutParams(params1);
             * relativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
             * 
             * @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
             * Log.e("error","here");
             * v.getParent().getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent
             * (true); return true; } });
             */
            WebView w = new WebView(getContext());
            AbsListView.LayoutParams params = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.height = 600;
            w.setLayoutParams(params);
            w.setScrollContainer(false);
            w.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            w.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            w.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
            w.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

            w.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return false;
                }
            });
            w.loadUrl(getItem(position));
            w.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    Log.e("error",event.getEventTime()+"");
                    v.getParent()
                            .requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

                    WebView scrollView =(WebView) v;

                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                            map.put(position, new ArrayList<Float>());

                        map.get(position).add(0,event.getX());
                        map.get(position).add(1,event.getY());
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                        float diff = (scrollView.getContentHeight()*scrollView.getScale()) - (scrollView.getScrollY()+600);
                       // Log.e("scrollView",scrollView.getContentHeight()*scrollView.getScale()+"   ");

                       // Log.e("diff",diff+"v.getBottom()"+ v.getBottom()+"v.getHeight()"+v.getHeight()+"v.getScrollY() "+v.getScrollY());
                       if (diff <= 0 ) {
                           scrollView.scrollTo((int)event.getX(), (int)(scrollView.getContentHeight()*scrollView.getScale()-600));
                            v.getParent()
                            .requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);

                          //Log.e("TestActivity", "bottom");
                          return false;
                        }if(v.getScrollY() < 0 ||  v.getHeight() > scrollView.getContentHeight()){
                            scrollView.scrollTo((int)event.getX(), (int)0);
                            v.getParent()
                            .requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                            // Log.e("TestActivity", "top");
                              return false;
                        }
                        float oldX =0;
                        float oldY = 0;
                        if(map.containsKey(position)){
                             oldX = map.get(position).get(0);
                             oldY = map.get(position).get(1);
                        }

                        float diffX = oldX -event.getX();
                        float diffY = oldY - event.getY();
                        //Log.e("Scroll To", "oldX "+ oldX+"oldY "+oldY+"diffX "+diffX+"diffY "+diffY+"event.getX() "+event.getX()+"event.getY() "+event.getY());
                        scrollView.scrollBy((int)diffX, (int)diffY);
                        Log.e("error",event.getEventTime()+"  =  "+diffY);
                        map.get(position).clear();
                        map.get(position).add(0,event.getX());
                        map.get(position).add(1,event.getY());
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }





                    return true;
                }
            });
            /*
             * scrollView.addView(w); relativeLayout.addView(scrollView);
             */
            return w;
            // return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

    }
}
```

and test_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```